# Can one 'interpolate' between trained points in supervized learning

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, simulation, physics, decision-tree

Sorry about the title but I am self-trained in machine learning and I am not sure that I use the terminus-technicus correctly.

So, the idea:
I want to reconstruct position of particle hits in segmented calorimeters.
To achieve this goal I simulate events and train ML algorithms (it has not decided yet what type) for *discrete* hit-positions in the calorimeter.
On the other hand in 'real-life' the particles can hit my detector everywhere on its front-surface.

The question is whether is there any way to 'interpolate' between the discrete training points to reconstruct the positions of a particle hit between these (trained) points ...

Lets talk about - for example - decision trees or artificial neural networks ...

Best Regards,
Karoly

Comment: Decision trees can definitely do this.  A trained tree (or forest) is a function like any other function.  Given a set of inputs, it will produce a response output.  This holds true even if you trained it using discrete data.

Comment: Err..What is a segmented calorimeter? Never heard of it in ML area. Found some papers on particle physics and cannot quite understand what it is. So, still not clear about the problem.

Comment: (roughly speaking) calorimeter: a type of detector that measures the energy a(n elementary) particle; segmented calorimeters: calorimeters built up from not one piece, but several pieces. If they are segmented transversely (put the pieces next to each-other) the deposited energy-fractions in the different detector elements can be used to determine the position where the particle hit the detector ... roughly speaking ...

Comment: k-Nearest Neighbors also performs a sort of interpolation of the training points.